# How do I make the Jelly potion?

Tags: candy-box

I've tried a handful of times and always come up jelly-less.

Anyone have more precise instructions for cooking jelly than are in the potion manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did:

- Add 600 candies
- Click boil
- Wait until water boils, then stop
- Add 6,000 lollipops
- Mix for 5 seconds, then stop
- Add 600 candies
- Click boil
- Wait until water boils, then stop

Comment: works.  Not sure why that one was tripping me up.  Thnx.